# How to make a div's marginLeft increment through button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to play around with jQuery and was wondering how I can acheive the following situation:

You have a button and a div.

```
<div class="test"></div>
<button id="move">Move</button>
```

You click the button, and the div's marginLeft gets incremented by 50px.

I have made the following jsFiddle that works for the first click, but not for any subsequent clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/9KgjQ/

```
$( "#move" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".test" ).css({
          marginLeft: function( margin, value ) {
              margin += 50;
              value = margin + "px";
              return value;
              }
      });
 });
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your marginLeft function has the wrong parameters. The first one is the index while the second one is the current value. So you could do this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#move" ).on( "click", function() {
        $( ".test" ).css({
            marginLeft: function( index, margin ) {
                margin = parseInt(margin, 10) + 50;
                value = margin + "px";
                return value;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#move" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".test" ).animate({
          "margin-left":"+=50px"
      });
   });

});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9KgjQ/4/)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah your function gives value of `margin` 0 all time. so margin += 50 remains 50 all time.

Comment: you were using `margin` instead of `margin-left`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(function() {

  $( "#move" ).on( "click", function() {
      var mleft= $( ".test" ).css('margin-left');
         mleft=mleft.split('p')[0]-0;
      var newMargin=+mleft+50;
      $( ".test" ).css('margin-left',newMargin+'px');

   });

});
```

**[New Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9KgjQ/9/)**

Comment: This doesn't really work since. After two clicks, the margin left becomes huge.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah it should work now. It just needed the mleft coerced to a number.